# JTable is not visible in Jframe

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel

I want to add a `Jtable` on `Jpanel` but the table is not appearing in frame after running this program.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    table = new JTable(Values,header);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(108, 74, 209, 112);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    table = new JTable();
    panel.add(table);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have done 
`panel.add(scroll);`
Instead of
`panel.add(table);`

Your code
 `table = new JTable();
    panel.add(table);` 
would have still shown something but the new table you created was empty, so nothing shows.